# Node.JS request data length is smaller than given in Content-Length

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, content-length

My request is a multipart/form-data

This is how I read the request data:

```
var data = "";

this.request.on( "data" , function( chunk ){

    data += chunk;

} );

this.request.on( "end" , function(){

    this.request.body = this.parseRequest( data );

    this.emit( "end" );

}.bind( this ) );
```

Now, the `Content-Length` of the request is **25,981**, but the length of data "on end" is **25,142**.

Can anyone explain please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was here:

`data += chunk;`

The `.toString()` method in buffer corrupts the binary data - that's where the length loss comes from.

Two solutions:

1. Keep chunk as a Buffer and work with it.
2. Use `.toString('binary')` which converts the buffer to string with no data loss (at least in my test).

My code now:

```
    var buffer = [];

    this.request.on( "data" , function( chunk ){
        buffer.push( chunk );
    } );

    this.request.on( "end" , function(){

        buffer = Buffer.concat( buffer );
        this.request.body = this.parseRequest( buffer.toString("binary") );
        this.emit( "end" );

    }.bind( this ) );
```